# AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'decode'

Tags: python

I'm trying read multiple text files, doing word segmentation (use `jieba`) and then save the results to CSV files respectively. It shows

```
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

Thanks for anyone's help.

The python code is:

```
import jieba
import csv
import glob

list_of_files = glob.glob('C:/Users/user/Desktop/speech./*.txt')           
for file_name in list_of_files:

    FI = open(file_name, 'r')
    FO = open(file_name, 'w')
    seglist = jieba.cut(FI, cut_all=False)
    w = csv.writer(FO)  
    w.writerows(seglist)  
    FI.close()
    FO.close()
```

Comment: Could you please paste the whole traceback and not the end line?

Comment: You should post the full Traceback, or at least enough of it so we can see what's generating that error message. I don't know `jieba`, but I suspect that `jieba.cut` expects a `bytes` string, not a file.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you need to send bytes to **cut** and not a file object

try this code instead:

```
list_of_files = glob.glob('C:/Users/user/Desktop/speech./*.txt')           
for file_name in list_of_files:
    with  open(file_name, 'rb') as f:
        text = f.read()


    seglist = jieba.cut(text, cut_all=False)

    with open(file_name, 'w') as f:
        w = csv.writer(f)  
        w.writerows(seglist)
```

Comment: +1 for the .read() suggestion.  I used this for an _io.BytesIO object which then let me do the .decode('utf-8') , which was the format I needed.

Answer (score 0):

From what I read from [source code as example](http://nullege.com/codes/search/jieba.cut) and [jieba.cut definition](https://github.com/fxsjy/jieba/blob/8ba26cf97e9de8d2319f238eda518e15800c48df/jieba/finalseg/__init__.py#L81) it seems `jieba.cut` needs string as parameter.

But you are giving an instance of `file`.

```
seglist = jieba.cut(FI.read(), cut_all=False)
```

Fixed the issue from what I saw. (*`FI.read()` is the fix*).

---

Btw, do not call variables like `FI` / `FO`, this is valid name for constants or maybe classes, but not variable.

*Explicit is better than implicit*: prefere something like: `file_output` & `file_input`.

Comment: It works now, thanks. Also thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: great, maybe you could validate and why not upvote if it helped :)

Comment: I hope to do so, but I need now is to accumulate 15 reputations first.